# Adding extra info before writing to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the Action method code below, all the data from the form is included as parameters, but what if I also would like to add to the table something more like the users Entity ID

```
var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

How can I add that to the Customers object before it's written to the table? One way could perhaps be to add it into the HTML and the form as hidden, but I guess it would be unsecure to have that visible in the code?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,FirtsName,LastName,PhoneNumber")] Customers customers)
    {

  var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Customers.Add(customers);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customers);
    }
```

Comment: post your `Customers` model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set some property before save.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,FirtsName,LastName,PhoneNumber")] Customers customers)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            customers.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Customers.Add(customers);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customers);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your code: customers.UserID = User..... the 'UserID' is the same as the name in the table?

Comment: Yes, it's the same field as the field in table, just use your name :)

Comment: I'm sure your code is working, but I suddenly got problems with the form. Despite that I'm enter a name, it's ask for a name when I click on the create button! What could be wrong?

Comment: Customers model and View.

Comment: That will be a lot of code! Do you have any ideas what could be wrong and I can look for it my self?

Comment: Can you explain it one more time, I'm not sure what is your problem now. You have view with form and input element to enter name (FirtsName from model?) and what happen when you click create button?

Comment: I get red text below the input field telling me that the FirstName is required! And despite that I enter a name, I get the same message all the time.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problems is, but I will accept your answer since you have answered my original question. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Maybe create new question with your view code and model, because without that I'm not sure what can be a problem.